# How do I install/uninstall drivers from CMD in windows7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, boot, drivers, motherboard

Recently I had to change the motherboard(different manufacturer and chipset) on one of my computers and now windows 7 wont start.
I would like to avoid reinstalling windows from scratch since it would take me a couple of days at least to get it to the same state.

So, my question is: How can I, from the command prompt of the recovery menu, uninstall the old motherboard drivers(and maybe graphics, ethernet and sound, just to be sure)? and should that not be enough, how can I manually install the new ones from the same CMD prompt?

Comment: Have you tried a repair install?

Comment: Did you try booting in safe mode? (via `F8`). That should disable most drivers. If that works you can either manually deinstall a lot of drivers or use sysprep to remove all of them.

Comment: In the recovery console you can use the "disable" command to disable drivers and services. Use "listsvc" to get a list of the services and drivers installed.

Comment: Sadly I don't have the installation disk(only the system repair disk that came with the computer) and that only takes me to the system recovery options. Safe mode doesn't work either. And I'll try to use the "disable" command now, I'll tell you if that worked.

Comment: Command prompt doesn't recognize the "listsvc" and "disable" commands, it's weird because I logged in with the administrator account. Dunno if related, but it cant find "ntbtlog.txt" either.

Comment: you can get a retail iso here http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/

Comment: Thanks. I did download it, but when I try to do a repair install(choosing the upgrade option) it tells me that I need to launch it from inside the OS so it's not an option to me. So far(an hour or so of google) I haven't found any way around that limitation.